# How to avoid lags while deactivating huge Gameobject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have an empty GameObject, chunk, with a plenty of children objects(about 1k with Colliders in each).It looks like selfmade TileMaps. The problem is that the time required to activate/deactivate this chunk is too long, so the game friezes. How can I avoid these lags without using a Tilemaps. And does it make sense to use chunks at all, or is it better to activate blocks one by one?

Comment: well yes activating them one by one might help to avoid a lag if you have that many objects. Do you enable/disable all of them or only the top-most parent? Maybe it would be enough to only disable a certain component instead and move it to a different layer so it isn't considered in collisions and not rendered? What exactly is your use case? In general having a lot of objects can slow down Unity a lot

Comment: @derHugo I only activate the parent component, is it slower than activating each by a loop?

Comment: Depends a lot on the components on your objects but in general: It won't get faster by doing it in a loop, no. **But** you could maybe spread the lag over multiple frames and thereby avoid a notable lag.